# Java concurrency - data structure to avoid concurrent modification of objects with same ID

Tags: java, concurrency

What would be the correct structure to use for the following case:

Let's say we have a stock system **(the domain is not really important, it's just an example)** and each operation is slow (contacting an external system for example).

- It handles ~ 50 warehouses (WH).
- I can move stock from one WH to another.
- I want to guarantee that the final stock is correct

What I was thinking about is that I can process in parallel requests that don't impact the same WH. e.g:

1. A request to move 20 items from WH 1 to 3
2. A request to move to move 15 items from 2 to 5 (it could be processed in parallel with the previous one)
3. A request to move 5 items from 3 to 6 comes (it should wait for the first request to finish before proceeding).

I was thinking about a thread safe map containing all the ids of the warehouses which I'm currently processing.

Is there something better?

Comment: How much time does it take to move from one WH to another? Because if it's fast, just making the move() method synchronized could be more than fast enough. I'd make it plain simple (and correct) first, and then optimize only if needed.

Comment: If you can't answer that question, then it's too broad. You can't expect a silver bullet solution that applies to every situation.

Comment: Yes, it's a slow operation. Also I'm not asking if it should or not be parallelized. I'm asking about a specific data structure.

Comment: Get the lock on WH1, then the lock on WH2, then move. Always use the same order (from lowest to highest number, for example) to avoid deadlocks.

Comment: I agree with @JBNizet. To add, you could use striped locks (i.e. map n warehouses to m locks).

Comment: You mean `com.google.common.util.concurrent.Striped`? Is there any native alternative on new java versions?

Comment: @JBNizet said, "...because if it's fast..." OK, but if it is _not_ fast, then what you do is define a `Truck` class. Then, you can lock whatever needs to be locked just long enough to quickly move the objects from warehouse 1 to a `Truck`. Then, some time later, you can lock whatever needs to be locked just long enough to quickly move the objects from the truck to warehouse 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest, you introduce a `lock` variable for each `Warehouse` object together with an unique integer number. You can use an `AtomicInteger` to ensure that each created warehouse has its unique number

```
public class Warehouse {
    private static final AtomicInteger numberProvider = new AtomicInteger(0);
    private final int number;
    private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    // ...
    public Warehouse(...) {
        this.number = numberProvider.incrementAndGet();
        ...
    }
    // ... (getter for number and lock and other methods)
}
```

With that you can always lock the two warehouses in the "correct" order (for example, first lock the lower number, then lock the higher; unlocking in backwards direction). This will guarantee that you won't run into deadlocks.

```
public void moveStock(Warehouse from, Warehouse to, int nof) {
    List<Lock> locks = Stream.of(from, to)
        .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Warehouse::getNumber))
        .map(Warehouse::getLock)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    for(int i=0;i<locks.size();++i) {
        locks.get(i).lock();
    }
    try {
        from.substractStock(nof);
        to.addStock(nof);
    } finally {
        for(int i=locks.size()-1;i>=0;i--) {
            locks.get(i).unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sets would be the Data Structure you are looking for.